# How can i convert index to integer?

Tags: python

The first print result i manage to find the index of the character 't'. I'm trying to use the result index to insert into guess position, so i can replace the asterisks which the char. But in this case i received error.

```
word = "python"
store = []
guess = ['*'] * len(word)
for index, char in enumerate(word):
    if char == 't':
        store.append(index)
        print("the index of i is: ", store)

        print(char)

        guess[store] = char
        print(''.join(guess))
```

Comment: The variable `store` is a *list*, not an index. Have you tried to use the variable actually *named* `index`?

Comment: I just start learning python last week.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this:

```
word = "python"
store = []
guess = ['*'] * len(word)
for index, char in enumerate(word):
    if char == 't':
        store.append(index)
        print("the index of '%s' is: %s"%(char, index))

        print(char)

        guess[index] = char #guess is list and index is integer here
        print(''.join(guess))
```

Comment: what is the different between index and store? aren't give the same number?

Comment: store is the list e.g. [2] and index is integer e.g. 2 you can use `index` or `store[0]`